# VS Code debugging: C++ Attach needs program?

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-code

I have a "C++ Attach" configuration for attaching `lldb` to `python`. One of the mandatory fields in the `launch.json` is `"program"`. Why do I have to specify a program if I want to debug another process anyway?

The [VS Code docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/debugging) are quite short on this topic, unfortunately.